# Memory Leak when using SharedPtr with std::list! Bug?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, poco, stdlist

**VLD have detected Memory Leak in follow codes:**

```
typedef Poco::SharedPtr<double> DoublePtr;
class A {
    public:
        DoublePtr a;
};

class B:public A {
    public:
        DoublePtr b;
};    

class C : public B
{
    public:
        DoublePtr c;

};

typedef Poco::SharedPtr<A> APtr;
typedef Poco::SharedPtr<B> BPtr;
typedef Poco::SharedPtr<C> CPtr;

class Test {
    public:
        Test() {
            CPtr c1 = new C();
            a_list.push_back(c1);
        }

        std::list<APtr> a_list;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Test test;
}
```

> But it's OK when using std::shared_ptr or boost::shared_ptr instead. 
>   And, if I add 'virtual ~A(){}', Poco::SharedPtr is OK too!
>
> ### Is the Bug of Poco::SharedPtr??

Comment: Does `Poco::SharedPtr` type-erase the deleter? Otherwise your code has UB on account of the non-virtual base destructor.

Answer (score 3):

`A` needs to have a virtual destructor; if it does not, then deleting a `B` or `C` object through an `A` pointer causes undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour may include memory leaks.